# Unable to create instance variable and class variable of the same name

Tags: swift

The following code does not compile:

```
class object {
    class var myVar: String! {
        return "from class"
    }

    var myVar: String! {
        return "from instance"
    }
}
```

Error:

> Invalid redeclaration of 'myVar'

Is this not possible with Swift or am I doing it wrong? This is totally legal in Objective-C (as functions rather than variables).

Comment: If you think that is a good idea file a radar. (I don't, it can easily cause confusion and errors.)

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you can't. If you really want to do this, you can file a [Bug Report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple.

I would advise against doing this. It's really bad practice, simply because having two different variables named the exact same thing, the only difference being how they are accessed, is a terrible code smell. And it's confusing.

So file a radar if you want to, and then change your variable names. I doubt Apple will "fix" this.

Comment: Totally agreed, it's very terrible.

Comment: I agree having same name might not be a good styling, but I don't think we need paint over the fact that it's a bug, just check out how other languages do (even in Objective-C)