# In Swift, why does an instance parameter and class function with same name produce invalid redeclaration error?

Tags: swift

Here's a contrived example:

```
class AwesomeClass {            
   var answerToEverything: NSInteger = 42

   class func answerToEverything() -> NSInteger {
    return 42
  }
}
```

Per my Swift understanding, there should be no issue here: `var answerToEverything` and `class func answerToEverything` have different signatures: `var answerToEverything` applies to the instance and `class func answerToEverything()` to the class.

However, this gives a compiler error:

`Invalid redeclaration of 'answerToEverything()`

Why does an instance parameter and class function with same names give this error?

In case it matters, I'm using Xcode 7.3 (7D175).

*Note: it makes sense why an **instance method** and **instance parameter** can't have the same name. The compiler couldn't distinguish them. However, this question is about a **class** method and an **instance** parameter. This is different from the proposed duplicate question.*

Comment: @JAL: Thanks for the link. However, this question is somewhat different.

Comment: The other question asks about an instance method and an instance parameter. This makes sense for why it's a bad idea--> as answered, which one should be used? The compiler can't really distinguish them. However, this question is about a *class method* and instance parameter. AFAIK, the compiler should be able clear distinguish them.

Comment: `AFAIK, the compiler should be able clear distinguish them.`  How?  Why do think so?

Comment: I was wrong, it is a bit different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016524/swift-variable-with-same-as-a-method-name. The real duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936426/unable-to-create-instance-variable-and-class-variable-of-the-same-name (as mentioned below). – Now someone else has to close as a duplicate!

Comment: @MartinR Yep, thanks. :-)

Comment: None of these are duplicates. You are taking the wrong assumption that all symbol types (class, class member, instance member, class function, instance function etc) are the same, and behave the same. This is obviously wrong for most compilers. Swift compiler is rather weird about this. There is absolutely no issue with such definitions in Obj-C, or even C for that purpose. The question is perfectly viable, and the issue is even more severe, as I will demonstrate in another comment.

Comment: I have it even worse. My class has member 'var playbackController : QPPlaybackController?' and a function 'func playbackController(_ playbackController: QPPlaybackController!, didFail error: QPError!)' . No one in right mind would expect these symbols to clash. The function signature cannot change - it implements an external Obj-C SDK's delegate method. While Swift will compile these together - there is NO WAY for me to actually CALL the function internally. Calling self.playbackController(xxx, didFail:qpError) will not compile - swift claims I'm calling a non-function (QPPlaybackController)

Answer (score 0):

`Identifiers` have to be unique, it's not about what their functions are. The same would happen in the following example:

```
let ViewController: Int = 10

class ViewController: NSViewController {

}
```

The initial variable won't be flagged up by the compiler, but the class will be flagged as a duplicate.

This doesn't apply if you:

1. define `let ViewController: Int = 10` in one Module
   and in another..
2. define `class ViewController: NSViewController`

The two two modules separate the identity spaces (namespaces in a way)

Comment: This is different. In your example, `ViewController` in both cases is within the same scope --> the compiler can't distinguish them.

Comment: However, instance parameters and class methods are in different scopes... One applies to the class and the other to the instance.

Comment: This also appears to be a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936426/unable-to-create-instance-variable-and-class-variable-of-the-same-name

Comment: I you want to be able to have duplicate names, file a rdar with Apple, but I see no benefit to this, if anything it seems more of a hinderance.

Comment: Yes, the previous question makes this a duplicate. Thanks! I don't _want_ to do this, but certain Foundation classes do this. Sigh, this effectively makes it impossible to subclass them in Swift. :(

Comment: Out of interest which Foundation frameworks/classes do this. It's be interesting to see how this is handled at the decompiled IR (llvm) level.

Comment: I believe all of the Foundation classes are written in Objective-C, where this is possible. However, subclassing is not possible/easy, though. In my case, I'm trying to subclass `NSDate` to create a custom mock for unit testing. `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` has both a property and class method with the same name.

Comment: The duplicate question is NOT a duplicate question.  This question is talking about instance variables and functions.