# Use of undeclared type 'Drug'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Im having a little trouble with my project. I keep getting two errors for "Use of undeclared type 'Drug'".

I have had a search online but can't solve the problem.

Here is the code that is causing the problem. The lines responsible is

let Drug: Drug

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let Drug : Drug
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        Drug = filtereddrugs[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        Drug = drugs[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.textLabel!.text = Drug.name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = Drug.category
    return cell
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filtereddrugs = drugs.filter({( Drug : Drug) -> Bool in
        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (Drug.category == scope)
        return categoryMatch && Drug.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
    })
    tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Segues
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let Drug: Drug
            if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                Drug = filtereddrugs[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                Drug = drugs[indexPath.row]
            }
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailDrug = Drug
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to SO, user's generally dont open up a uploaded project and fix it . Give some code.. we dont know what your code looks like,..

Comment: Welcome to [SO], please review the help section about what to ask, and how to ask it. Please **include** your code in the question.

Comment: I will edit the question now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change `let Drug : Drug` to `let drug : Drug`. I am assuming Drug has already been defined elsewhere. Of course all other cases of `Drug` as a variable need to be changed to `drug`

Comment: It's not the problem, I run it in Playgrounds and let Drug : Drug works well.

Comment: There is no reference above to how Drug is defined . But you cannot have a variable name the same as a class identifier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936426/unable-to-create-instance-variable-and-class-variable-of-the-same-name

Comment: @pedrouan:  It *is* a problem, try `func foo () { let Int: Int }` in a compiled project. – Calling the variable `Drug` *hides* the type with the same name.

Comment: yeah changing Drugs to drugs removed the error signs but the code doest run

Comment: @MartinR so playgrounds environment compiles differently? http://pasteboard.co/gxVDHK3rw.png

Comment: "code doesn't run" really doesn't say much and regardless, the question was in regards to compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
let drug = Drug()
```

Instead of:

```
let Drug : Drug
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared a type `Drug`, you should never name a variable like that type.

Better use: `let drug: Drug`

---

To prevent such mistakes, it is helpful to use the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

For example variable-names should start with a lowercase letter:

> **Follow case conventions**. Names of types and protocols are `UpperCamelCase`. Everything else is `lowerCamelCase`

It is a really long list of guidelines, but there are tools to check your code for these rules.